# Editing out text from a preformatted photo

Tags: text

I am very inexperienced in graphic design so please go easy on me.

I would like to edit out just one of the text boxes from this image. 
[image]

What is the easiest way to go about this? 
I was trying to cover the three ones in the middle that I don't want with blank text boxes and then shading them, but I cant make it work :(

Comment: Where are the three ones? What program do you plan on using to do the edit?

Comment: g <--> T, A <--> J and psi <--> O are the ones I'm trying to no avail to remove. Unfortunately the only program other than word and powerpoint is Inkscape :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inkscape only? No problem, it's as good option, because it works well as long as you stay outside the event horizon.

Seriously: ANY photo editor would be better. Consider to get Paint.NET, it's free and with it's cloning tool you easily copy the needed parts from elsewhere to cover the unwanted tensor references. It's easy to fade all borders in a photo editor.

In Inkscape:

Paste or import your image to Inkscape. (Beware taking it as a screenshot or copying it from MS Office - those make low resolution versions, use the sharpest version you can get)

Make a copy of the image. Lock the original in the Objects panel.

Draw onto the copy with the Pen tool a curve around one removable part.

[image]

Then move the curve to a place where the replacement can be taken from:

[image]

Rotate the curve a little, if needed to get good texture direction

Select the curve and the image, goto Object > Mask > Set, all of the image outside the curve vanishes.

Raise the snippet to top to keep it visible. Move the snippet onto the original copy of the image. Place it carefully, rotate, if needed and lock it in the objects panel. Result:

[image]

Release temporarily the locking of the original to make a new copy for new snippet.

Your image size in megabytes grows along each snippet, but that shouldn't be a problem, because finally you make an original size image

When you export as PNG you get again one bitmap image. Be sure to have original resolution, it's far too easy to forget it and get a piece of useless blur. Do not kill the composition before you have seen that the export is as sharp as the original.

**Technically easiest way:** Get the original drawing and insert only those texts which you need. Or edit the original composition file which still has editable texts over the drawn & scanned illustration.

Comment: Good gracious you're a wizard! I am very novice so all of these commands are very over my head but I will post my results when I'm done so you can be proud of me :) Thank you sir!!!!!!!